# Efficient weak form for numerically generating a static magnetic field from arbitrary current distribution (FEM)

Tags: electromagnetism, computational-physics

This may stray into computational physics, but I'm curious to know if there is some more efficient way for what I am trying to do. Perhaps a better gauge formulation is needed.

Consider two subdomains ($\Omega_M$, and $\Omega_J$) of some volume $\Omega$. Here, the current distribution $\textbf{J} = \textbf{J}(\textbf{r})$ is nonzero on $\Omega_J$. In a simple example, this can be thought of as a wire embedded in some medium.

The magnetic field $\textbf{H}$ obeys

$$\nabla \times \textbf{H} = \textbf{J}$$

Moving $\textbf{J}$ to the other side, multiplying by a test(trial) function, $\psi_h$ and integrating over the volume $\Omega$ gives,

$$\int\limits_\Omega \,\,d\Omega \,\,\psi_h(\textbf{r})\left[\nabla \times \textbf{H}(\textbf{r}) - \textbf{J}(\textbf{r}) \right] = 0$$

In my opinion, this would be a sufficient residual (three terms for each component) for solving for variables $H_x, H_y, H_z$, given the correct Jacobians supplied for Newton's method. Unfortunately, my solver is not able to find a solution. I've tried a variety of preconditioning methods and Jacobi-free approaches.

Perhaps because this problem (a wire example) has a solution that is degenerate about the cylindrical coordinate $\phi$ rotation and this is the nature of the convergence problems. There is also another condition, that $\nabla \cdot \textbf{B}(\textbf{r}) =  \nabla \cdot (\mu \textbf{H}(\textbf{r})) = 0$ must be satisfied, but I have not seen any improvement on convergence by adding in this constraint.

I'm aware of another approach, where you solve $\nabla^2 \textbf{A}(\textbf{r}) = \textbf{J}(\textbf{r})$ with $\nabla \cdot \textbf{A}(\textbf{r}) = 0$, but this requires higher order elements to handle to second derivative.

Has anyone done this or know of literature to help convey understanding on how to do this *on the finite elements*? I know commercial codes like ANSYS or Comsol have "electromagnetics" packages, but they greatly obscure the governing equations one uses (by not telling the user what the code does!) which in a way is letting the user ignore the important mathematical physics.

Comment: Did you look at the open source solver documentation?

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with what is available. I'm using PETSc within the MOOSE/libMesh framework.

I was able to get convergence of the nonlinear residual to about 1e-8 using superlu_dist but the solution is not a field that falls off 1/r from a wire symmetric about $\phi$. I don't really think this is a numerical or computational problem, but more of an issue with the physics called at the weak-form level.

Comment: If you know the current distribution, then the field is just a plain integration away. If the integrals don't agree with the field solver, then, I am afraid, the field solver has a serious numerical problem and needs to be debugged or, worst case, thrown away.

Comment: Well, what we are trying to do is develop a set of codes where the user inputs the current distribution. It could be some sort of coil design with standard electric current or some sort of coupled current- phase field distribution, which in a way is very general. In other words, the current could depend on system variables that themselves may also depend on some other PDE.

Comment: As long as the problem is quasi-static and there is no magnetic material involved, the problem is just an integration, though. What you are saying is that your field solver converges but not to the correct answer.